# Understanding HTTP function inside Alexa Skill-- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, httprequest, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently learning how to connect my Amazon Lambda function (in js) to an API. I found the following code which works but I am new to javascript and APIs in general and am not sure what it is doing. Could someone explain to me what this function does and how it works? Thanks!

```
function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
      host: 'api.icndb.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/jokes/random',
      method: 'GET',
    };

    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `response` object is a node.js [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), a 'push' stream in particular. ([This](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/a-brief-history-of-node-streams-pt-2-bcb6b1fd7468) article does a good job of explaining push/pull streams).

```
const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
  // Your request has been successfully made and you are 
  // handed a response object which is a stream, which will emit
  // a 'data' event when some data is available.
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  let returnData = '';

  // A chunk of data has been pushed by the stream,
  // append it to the final response
  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    returnData += chunk;
  });

  // All the data has been pushed by the stream.
  // 'returnData' has all the response data. Resolve the 
  // promise with the data.
  response.on('end', () => {
    resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
  });

  // Stream has thrown an error.
  // Reject the promise
  response.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
  });
});
request.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution. Create a function to getRemoteData and/or postRemoteData.

```
getRemoteData (url) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
          .get(url)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            resolve(res.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }) 
    },
    
    postRemoteData (url, body) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
          .post(url, body)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            resolve(res.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }) 
    },
```

Then use these functions in your IntentsHandlers.

```
//Get
const url = "https://anydir.com"
let speakOutput = "No data";
await logic.getRemoteData(url)
  .then((data) => {
      speakOutput = data.results.toString();
  })

//Post
const url = "https://anydir.com"
let speakOutput = "No data";
await logic.getRemoteData(url, {param1:valueParam1,param2:valueParam2})
    .then((data) => {
         speakOutput = data.results.toString();
    })
```

Example.

```
const NumberCharactersIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'NumberCharactersIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"
        let speakOutput = "No data";
        await logic.getRemoteData(url)
          .then((data) => {
            speakOutput = `There are ${data.results.length.toString()} in the Rick and Morty serie` 
        })

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```